# Linear regression model with integration of MLFlow

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, azure-databricks, mlflow

Does anybody has a link to sample Linear Regression code integrated with MLFlow and explaining all three concepts of MLFlow i.e. Tracking, Project and Model?

I'm particularly looking for a demo link to the same.

Comment: You can find a relevant example here: https://medium.com/@khanderao/quick-machine-learning-training-prototype-with-recently-opensourced-mlflow-9a6ed87be9bd

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation for MLflow has a [tutorial](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tutorial.html#tutorial) that walks through a linear regression example covering the tracking server, mlflow projects, and model serving.

For an end to end example of MLflow in action, just watch [Matei Zaharia's keynote](https://youtu.be/n7thin5UIeU?t=491) from Spark + AI Summit 2018.  He covers tracking, projects, and models, all using a linear regression example.